# How to get scroll velocity after ACTION_UP in Android

Tags: android, scroll, velocity, motionevent

During a swipe event, there are three stages: ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, and ACTION_UP. I want to continuously detect the swipe velocity after ACTION_UP until the velocity becomes zero.

Currently, I am using velocityTracker for detection, but since the finger has already left the screen, I cannot measure the current swipe velocity. I would like to ask if there is any method to measure the decreasing velocity after ACTION_UP?